# Django - How do I add a placeholder on a modelform that's the current field of the model?

Tags: django, django-forms, placeholder, modelform

I want to be able to vary the placeholder like so:

```
<input placeholder=" {{ input.placeholder }}">
```

Where input is a `model` with the "placeholder" `field`. The placeholder field will vary since I'll be using a formset, and each placeholder will vary.

Here's my `modelForm`

```
class Value(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = ValueModel
    fields = ['value_text']
    widgets = {
        'value_text': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
```

and my `modelformset`

```
values_formset = modelformset_factory(model=ValueModel, extra=0, form=Value)
```

I've tried

```
class Value(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Value, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['value_text'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = self.fields['placeholder']

class Meta:
    model = ValueModel
    fields = ['value_text', 'placeholder']
    widgets = {
        'value_text': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
```

And other attempts at trying to modify the `self.fields` with no success.

Edit: The relevant part of my `views.py`:

```
def page_view(request, values_id):
    values_form =  values_formset(queryset=ValueModel.objects.filter(
        values_id=values_id))

    context = {'value': values_form}
    return render(request, 'view.html', context)
```

My template view:

```
{{ value.management_form }}
{% for form in value %}
{{ form.id }}
{{ form.value_text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you post the whole view?

Comment: @WillKeeling Updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.fields['placeholder']` refers to a form field object, not a value; you couldn't use it as a placeholder. But it seems like what you want is to use the value of the model instance.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Value, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['value_text'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = self.instance.placeholder
```